# Should static constexpr class member variables be defined even if they are not ODR-used?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose the following class definition in a header file:

```
class foo
{
public:
    static float constexpr MY_VALUE{100.f};
};
```

In my CPP file, I have this:

```
float constexpr foo::MY_VALUE;
```

However, if `foo::MY_VALUE` is never ODR-used, should I define it? Does defining it when it isn't ODR-used hurt anything? Is it a good rule of thumb to always provide a definition like this for class static constexpr variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit opinion based IMO, but trying to stay technical... from the definition you don't have to do it, unless it is ODR-used, so it seems trivial. Don't. Also, a user can always provide definition for the context they needs.

As for the rule of thumb, one can also refer to:

> **3.2 One definition rule.** p3
>
> A variable x whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression ex is odr-used unless x satisfies
> the requirements for appearing in a constant expression (5.19) and, if x is an object, ex is an element of
> the set of potential results of an expression e, where either the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied
> to e, or e is a discarded-value expression (Clause 5). [...]

Taken from [c++14 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf).

So I would say: if you predict that your constant will be used in a non-const context I'd provide a definition for convenience. If not, then not. But it's a design decision one has to make.

Comment: "if you predict that your constant will be used in a non-const context" -- Perhaps worth adding is that this includes passing it by `const &`, and that many standard library function templates take parameters by `const &`.

Comment: Do you think that maybe changing the wording to *non-`constexpr`* context would suffice? I was probably too lousy. `const` and `constexpr` are different things indeed.

Comment: It's complicated enough to find proper wording that personally, I'd settle for providing clear examples. If you do want to change the wording, then perhaps something like "if you predict that your constant will be used in such a way that the compiler cannot immediately replace it by the constant's value, for instance when taking its address" would work?